# MongoDB: Match documents where object of arrays of objects does not equal given value

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, object, nosql

Here is my database with only relevant fields:

```js
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId('641b5665894f755f6dc422a2'),
    directMsgs: {
      person1: [
        {
          authorId: ObjectId('6454bb4e33b90133ba752e96'),
          isRead: false
        },
        {
          authorId: ObjectId('641b5665894f755f6dc422a2'),
          isRead: true
        }
      ],
      person2: [
        {
          authorId: ObjectId('641b5665894f755f6dc422a2'),
          isRead: true
        },
        {
          authorId: ObjectId('642b5765834f755f6dc422b3'),
          isRead: true
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Here is what is looks like after projection:

```js
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId('641b5665894f755f6dc422a2'),
    directMsgs: [
      {
        k: 'person1',
        v: [
          {
            authorId: ObjectId('6454bb4e33b90133ba752e96'),
            isRead: false
          },
          {
            authorId: ObjectId('641b5665894f755f6dc422a2'),
            isRead: true
          }
        ],
      },
      {
        {
          k: 'person2',
          v: [
            {
              authorId: ObjectId('641b5665894f755f6dc422a2'),
              isRead: true
            },
            {
              authorId: ObjectId('642b5765834f755f6dc422b3'),
              isRead: true
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to be able to check if a user has any unread messages where the `authorId` of a message is not equal to the user's `_id`. Here is what I've tried:

```js
const userId = '641b5665891f755f6dd422a2'
const uid = new ObjectId(userId)

const data = await User.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $project: { 
                directMsgs: { $objectToArray: '$directMsgs'} 
            }
        },
        { 
            $match: { 
                _id: uid, 
                'directMsgs.v.authorId': { $ne: uid }, 
                'directMsgs.v.isRead': false 
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

The matching seems to work fine without this line: `'directMsgs.v.authorId': { $ne: uid }`. Also if I change that to `'directMsgs.v.authorId': uid`, it matches as you'd expect. There seems to be a problem with the `$ne` operator. What would you guys do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the MongoDB [`$match` documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#mongodb-pipeline-pipe.-match)

> $match
> takes a document that specifies the query conditions. The query syntax is identical to the read operation query syntax; i.e.
> $match
> does not accept raw aggregation expressions. Instead, use a $expr query expression to include aggregation expression in
> $match.

The query is not working when you trying to achieve filtering with an operator in the `$match` stage:

```
'directMsgs.v.authorId': { $ne: uid }
```

You should work with the `$expr` operator.

`$match` stage

1. `$and` - Filter the document matching multiple conditions.

   1.1. Match the document by `_id`

   1.2. `$ne` - Compare the result of *1.2.1* is not empty array.

   1.2.1 `$filter` - Filter the document in the array.

   `input` - `$reduce` - Flatten the nested array `directMsgs.v` into a one-level array.

   `cond` - Match the document by `authorId` is not equal to `uid` and `isRead` equal to `false`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      directMsgs: {
        $objectToArray: "$directMsgs"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $and: [
          {
            _id: uid
          },
          {
            $ne: [
              {
                $filter: {
                  input: {
                    $reduce: {
                      input: "$directMsgs.v",
                      initialValue: [],
                      in: {
                        $concatArrays: [
                          "$$value",
                          "$$this"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  cond: {
                    $and: [
                      {
                        $ne: [
                          "$$this.authorId",
                          uid
                        ]
                      },
                      {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$this.isRead",
                          false
                        ]
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              []
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/9T4qXqORb2d)

Comment: Thank you! Your solution works in mongo playground but not when implemented in my code. I fixed this by moving the `$expr` inside of the `$and`, like this: `$and: [ { _id: uid }, { $expr: .... } ]`. It seems to be working fine now